# Вопрос по спискам в Vue

Tags: vue.js

Ребят, проясните вопрос: почему вид списка меняется от переменной {{bear}} и {{bears}}? Неужели vue распознает множественное число?

[image: Правильный список]

```
<ul class="list">
     <li class="item" v-for="bear in bears">{{bear}}</li>
</ul>
```

[image: Неправильный список]

```
<ul class="list">
     <li class="item" v-for="bear in bears">{{bears}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Он просто выводит то, что ты ему сказал, предварительно преобразовав в строку.

> ```
> <li class="item" v-for="bear in bears">{{bear}}</li>
> ```

```js
var bears = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var bear of bears) {
  console.log('' + bear);
}
```

> ```
> <li class="item" v-for="bear in bears">{{bears}}</li>
> ```

```js
var bears = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var bear of bears) {
  console.log('' + bears);
}
```